# Web page components animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I'm a beginner learning front end development. I'm curious to know and learn how other developers create animated component like the one in below site.

https://bzx.network/

Do we have a tool that will let us create this? Where I can learn these? I couldnot find the tool, right search keyword in google, stackoverflow.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you look using your browser's dev tools at the image  you'll see it's made up of SVG components. There are several ways of animating - using CSS, JS and/or within SVG itself. Certainly you need to learn the basics of CSS animation anyway, and for SVGs google something like how to animate SVGs.  animating along paths is particularly useful. There's lots of tools to help, but SO doesn't like recommendations on this sort of thing.

Comment: animate SVGs -thats the keyword. Thanks @AHaworth - add your comment to answers, I will mark it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look using your browser's dev tools at the image you'll see it's made up of SVG components.

There are several ways of animating

- using CSS
- JavaScript
- and/or within SVG itself.

Certainly you need to learn the basics of CSS animation anyway, but I don’t think that’s what’s been used here.

For SVGs google something ‘like how to animate SVGs’. Animating along paths is particularly useful and I suspect that is what is being done here.

There's lots of tools to help, but SO doesn't like recommendations on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good website to play with animations and understand what can be achieved: https://animista.net/
You can play around with a lot of default animations and the website will produce the code that you can paste into your project.

I leave you also a link for one of the best guides on CSS animations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Answer (score 1):

For adding any type of animation or animated content, one must know javascript.
There are many javascript libraries which are used to add the animations such as [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/), [GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/) and many more.

Also there are some websites where yoou can design the animation and then you will get the code to add it in your code. One such website is [Animista](https://animista.net/).